# MYSQL - List specific columns

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query which lists the names of the columns in an SQL table, however, I don't want all the columns - just specific ones. So, for example, if I was to put the COMMENT = 'test' for the columns which I want to list then I thought my query would be:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `tbl_name` WHERE `COMMENT`='test'
```

This however throws an error.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think its possible. `SHOW` is not a `SELECT`. So no `WHERE ` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do this using `information_schema.columns`:

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns c
where table_name = 'tbl_name' and
      column_comment = 'test';
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I just looked up the information.schema and it means I can essentially categorise my columns now for different users. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that SHOW COLUMNS can't have the WHERE clause, but you can try this:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM (SELECT * FROM `tbl_name` WHERE `COMMENT`='test')
```